# Express non-negativity contraint on polynomial with coefficients on unit interval

Tags: polynomials

Given a polynomial of order $N$ with coefficients $\{c_0,\ldots,c_{N-1} \}$:

$P(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} c_i x^i$ with $x \in [0,1]$,

what is the most general way to express the non-negativity constraint $P(x) \geq 0$ as a constraint on the coefficients $\{ c_i \}$?

For example, if $ \{ \forall i: c_i \geq 0 \}$, it follows trivially that $P(x) \geq 0$ with $x \in [0,1]$. However, the polynomials with $ \{ \forall i: c_i \geq 0 \}$ are only a subset of all polynomials with $P(x) \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a more general easy rule, You need $c_0>0$ and that the number of sign variations in the coefficient sequence (resp. sequence of values of all derivatives) at $x=0$ is the same as in $x=1$ (Budan-Fourier theorem).

Another way to look at it is to transform the interval $[0,1]$ to the interval $[0,\infty)$ via

$Q(x)=(1+x)^n\cdot P((1+x)^{-1})$.

Then if all coefficients are positive, there will be no roots [edit] by Descartes rule of signs. Of course, even with negative coefficients, however only with an even number of sign variations, there might be zero real positive roots.

---

This is still not the most general rule, for that you need the Sturm sequence of the polynomial, which gives an exact count for the number of real roots.

---

Added 12/20: I have just learned about the Schur-Cohn test based on the Schur transform of polynomials which allows to count the number of roots inside the unit circle in the complex plane. This could be applied here to the shifted and scaled polynomial $q(z)=p(\tfrac{1+z}2)$.

One could also compute the number of roots via the winding number of $q(e^{it})$, which can use the iFFT to obtain a large enough sampling of polynomial values on that circle.

Comment: Thanks for the right keywords. I will take a look at Sturm's theorem.